# Two Different components with same URL(passing slug in router with lazy loading) in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular-components

How can I solve two different components with passing only slug? I'm getting first component(ItemModule) for both the cases.

**routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    children: [{
      path: ':itemSlug',
      loadChildren: '../item/item.module#ItemModule'
    }],
{
    path: '',
    children: [{
      path: ':brandSlug',
      loadChildren: '../brand/brand.module#BrandModule'
    }]
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [{
path: '',
component: MainComponent
},
{
    path: 'slug',


    children: [{
      path: 'itemSlug',
      loadChildren: '../item/item.module#ItemModule'
    },
{
      path: 'brandSlug',
      loadChildren: '../brand/brand.module#BrandModule'
    }
]];
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: But in this case I'll get URL like domainName/slug/itemSlug and domainName/slug/brandSlug. And my URL should domainName/itemSlug where itemSlug is passing throug selection of any button. I'm not going to add 'itemSlug' as keyword. that may be any number or string

Comment: In that case make the path empty. Usually You need to add an empty path for default URL. and specific paths for the determined navigation location. If you really want to have the way you commented, remove the empty path stuff and have the path '' for path:'slug'

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: Whether it helped you, is my concern!

Comment: Yes. It's very helpful to me

Comment: Then you can up-port and take it as the answer. Thanks! :)